# Random sample of n rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to sample n rows from a table at random. Alas

```sql
SELECT * FROME testtable sample (10 rows);
```

as [the docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/sample.html) suggest gives me:

```
SQL compilation error: Sampling with sample missing tag for parameter seed.
```

Tagging on `SEED(123)` gives me

```
SQL compilation error: Sampling with sample wrong number of arguments for parameter seed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work okay for me. Are you sure that's a table you are sampling on and not a view / materialised view or anything?

If you have access to the `snowflake_sample_data` database could you try this and see?

```sql
select 
    * 
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.customer sample (10 rows)
;
```

Comment: I do have access to the data and get the same error message.

Comment: @RoyalTS raise a request with Snowflake then I reckon

Comment: nod, the above example works fine form my account, so agree with the raise a ticket comment.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, you want to randomly select 10 rows from a table.

The following can help to achieve this result:

```
select * from testtable 
order by RANDOM(123)
limit 10;
```

Comment: Yeah, that certainly works. It was just my understanding that `SAMPLE` has better performance than `ÒRDER BY RANDOM()`

Comment: I'm going to have to test this to confirm, but I think this won't actually sample the table. It will randomize the limited row set, but the row set will be (I think) the results of a race condition.